# Making a Map in Gloss

Tags: haskell, gloss

In PL class we were asked to make a pacman clone in [Gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss), nevertheless I got stuck at making the map.

My approach was taking a .png of the classical pacman first level, and paste it in the render function so I don't need to draw everything by hand.

Nevertheless by doing so, the games lags horribly, I'm assuming that it's because the game renders the map in every step.

Is there some way to just render the map as a background a single time, or avoid the huge lag? Or am I taking a bad approach and it would it be better if I draw the components by hand using the [Picture](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.13.1.2/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html) module?

I append the render function just in case I'm wiring it badly:

```
render :: PacmanGame -> IO Picture
render game = do
  sprite <- fmap (head) (playerSprites $ player game)
  let playerOne = uncurry translate (playerPos $ player game) $ sprite
  map' <- pacmanMap 
  return $ pictures [map', playerOne]
```

Where `pacmanMap :: IO Picture`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re *reloading* the file in every call to `render`. You need to run the `pacmanMap :: IO Picture` action *once*, for example at startup in `main`; then you can just return the resulting static `Picture` from your `render` function. For example, you might store the reference to the current background image in the `PacmanGame`, or pass it as an additional argument to `render`.

Comment: Many thanks! I binded pacmanMap to a variable in Main, then passed that as a parameter to render and the lag went away. This gives me a new perspective when working with bindings.